# Download a file through rundeck UI?

Tags: rundeck

Is there a way to have rundeck download a file to the user (through the browser)?  We have developers that request files from our production and qa environments that the admin team has to fetch for them.  Would like to setup a rundeck job that would allow them to specify the node and filename and (if they have permissions) have it fetch the file and allow them to download it through their browser.   The first part, fetching the file to the rundeck server is easy enough, but I looked through the list of plugins and didn't see anything that would offer the browser download part.

Rundeck 3.3.9.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with an http server (apache, nginx, etc). Currently, I have a job that run a bash script. This script log output to a file located at some directory served by apache httpd server.

For example, in apache config file

```
Alias /jobs "/internal/file/path"
<Directory "/internal/file/path">
    Options Indexes MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Now you can access job output by going to http://your_url/jobs

Then, you can secure this directory access with specific apache directives.

Another way to reach you goal is to use webdav. You can copy yout target file to a webdav location (served by apache) and then print location on rundeck job output).

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the response!   Would consider, but our rundeck project got cancelled after business found out how much the enterprise edition cost (wanted the sso and task/workflow capabilities of the EE version) ....